# Пытаюсь установить через pip aiohttp jinja2 aiohttp-jinja2, выдаёт ошибку

Tags: python, pip, jinja2, aiohttp

```
Collecting aiohttp
  Downloading aiohttp-3.7.4.post0.tar.gz (1.1 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 1.1 MB 656 kB/s
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
    Preparing wheel metadata ... error
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Надя\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' 'C:\Users\Надя\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pe
p517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\C344~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpqpkvzb0s'
         cwd: C:\Users\Надя\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-7wszbeku\aiohttp_c2be6369a39748158ddd24afafb58027
    Complete output (25 lines):
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 7)
    running dist_info
    creating C:\Users\Надя\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-yufimpby\aiohttp.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\Надя\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-yufimpby\aiohttp.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Надя\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-yufimpby\aiohttp.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to C:\Users\Надя\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-yufimpby\aiohttp.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\Надя\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-yufimpby\aiohttp.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Надя\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-yufimpby\aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\Надя\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-yufimpby\aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching 'aiohttp' anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lib' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.a' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.obj' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'aiohttp\*.html'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
    adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Надя\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-yufimpby\aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    creating 'C:\Users\Надя\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-yufimpby\aiohttp.dist-info'
    error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'C:\Users\Надя\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe' -u -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Надя\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c3
l88le_\\multidict_f6703efbc7224b33ab34310c40d22f7f\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Надя\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-c3l88le_\\multidict_f6703efbc7224b33ab34310c40d22f7f\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"
', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' install --r
ecord 'C:\Users\Надя\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_9fg71yc\install-record.txt' --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Надя\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Include\multidict' Check the logs fo
r full command output.
```